# Get key pressed event

Tags: python, get, key, pressed

I'm developing translation software for Linux using Python. I'm looking for a way to get the key pressed event. When an english letter key is pressed, I wan the pressed key to be assigned to a variable.

I've tried googling and reading various articles, but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Is this a terminal app, or an X/GUI app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/), you care about the `Pygame.KEYDOWN` [keyboard event](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html). You can see how to use it in the pygame example [aliens.py](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/b83d8cc291ff/examples/aliens.py).

Comment: No friend. this is not what I want. In your solution I have to check all the keys to find the pressed key. What I exactly want is somthing else. while program is running, if any key is pressed, I want to run a while loop with assigning the pressed key to a variable as a character. I think you understood my problem. :)

Comment: I think you can get what you're looking for by running the while loop as in aliens.py and calling a callback with the pressed key. Admittedly it's a little more cumbersome than I'd like.